# Как в API перейти на другую страницу

Tags: python, json, api

Подскажите пожалуйста. Хочу взять данные игр с апишки, но там все разбито на странице. Пробовала перейти на другую страницу, итерируя в мета словаре номер страницы, но она все-равно парсит только первую, просто много раз.
https://pastebin.com/DCUkrfqf
Вот апишка, откуда беру данные https://www.balldontlie.io
Основной вопрос, как перейти на следующую current_page

Comment: У вас почему то только 1 requests.get и параметр page в нем не передается. надо выполнять его в цикле по страницам меняя параметр page

Comment: curen_page итерирует, вот только сама страница не меняется

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. Нужно делать гет для этой же ссылки, или как-то указать номер другой страницы?

Comment: Так вы сами меняете значение current_page на i. конечно он у вас увеличивается. но вы это делаете исключительно внутри изначально полученной по api страницы, только у себя в памяти. А должны вызывать API для каждой страницы еще раз, передавая параметр page

Comment: В описании API написано, должен быть параметр page, начинающийся с нуля. Ссылка должна быть вида `https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/stats?seasons[]=" + str(season) +'&page=' + str(N)` где N это номер страницы

Comment: А, большое спасибо